# Very slow dir()

Tags: file, matlab, dir

When there are many files, around 4000, `dir()` function is very slow. My guess is it creates a structure and filling in the values in an inefficient way.

Are there any fast and elegant alternatives to using `dir()`?

Update: Testing it in 64 Bit, Windows 7 with MATLAB R2011a.

Update 2: It takes around 2 seconds to complete.

Comment: Use a mask to list only the files you want `dir *data*.m`, for example

Comment: @jonsca: I need all the files in the directory, so I need all ~4000 file names.

Comment: How slow is it actually?

Comment: I'd lay odds that the files are located on a network or USB drive, which would explain the slow performance.

Comment: @gnovice: you may be right, I will try Jason's solution and if that is slow too, I will check the performance of reading from HDD and USB disk.

Answer (score 8):

Which CPU / OS are you using? I just tried it on my machine with a directory with 5000 files and it's pretty quick:

```
>> d=dir;
>> tic; d=dir; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.062197 seconds.
>> tic; d=ls; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.139762 seconds.
>> tic; d=dir; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.058590 seconds.
>> tic; d=ls; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.063663 seconds.
>> length(d)

ans =

        5002
```

The other alternative to MATLAB's ls and dir functions is to directly use Java's `java.io.File` in MATLAB:

```
>> f0=java.io.File('.');
>> tic; x=f0.listFiles(); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.006441 seconds.
>> length(x)

ans =

        5000
```

Answer (score 7):

Confirmed Jason S's suggestion for a networked drive and for a directory containing 363 files. Win7 64-bit Matlab 2011a.

Both `foo` and `bar` below yield the same cell array of filenames (verified using MD5 hashing of the data), but `bar` using Java takes significantly less time. Similar results are seen if I generate `bar` first and then `foo`, so this isn't a network caching phenomenon.

```
>> tic; foo=dir('U:\mydir'); foo={foo(3:end).name}; toc
Elapsed time is 20.503934 seconds.
>> tic;bar=cellf(@(f) char(f.toString()), java.io.File('U:\mydir').list())';toc
Elapsed time is 0.833696 seconds.
>> DataHash(foo)
ans =
84c7b70ee60ca162f5bc0a061e731446
>> DataHash(bar)
ans =
84c7b70ee60ca162f5bc0a061e731446
```

where `cellf = @(fun, arr) cellfun(fun, num2cell(arr), 'uniformoutput',0);` and `DataHash` is from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31272. I skip the first two elements of the array returned by `dir` because they correspond to `.` and `..`.

Comment: Thank you!  Instead of cellf, you can use `arrayfun` directly: `bar = arrayfun(@(f) char(f.toString()), java.io.File('U:\mydir').list(),'UniformOutput',false);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try [LS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ls.html). It returns only file names in character array. I didn't test if it faster than DIR.

UPDATE:

I checked on a directory with over 4000 files. Both `dir` and `ls` show similar results: about 0.34 sec. Which is not bad I think. (MATLAB 2011a, Windows 7 64-bit)

Is your directory located on a local hard drive or network? May be defragmenting the hard drive will help?

Answer (score 1):

%Example: list files and folders

```
Folder = 'C:\'; %can be a relative path
jFile = java.io.File(Folder); %java file object
Names_Only = cellstr(char(jFile.list)) %cellstr
Full_Paths = arrayfun(@char,jFile.listFiles,'un',0) %cellstr
```

%Example: list files (skip folders)

```
Folder = 'C:\';
jFile = java.io.File(Folder); %java file object
jPaths = jFile.listFiles; %java.io.File objects
jNames = jFile.list; %java.lang.String objects
isFolder = arrayfun(@isDirectory,jPaths); %boolean
File_Names_Only = cellstr(char(jNames(~isFolder))) %cellstr
```

%Example: simple filter

```
Folder = 'C:\';
jFile = java.io.File(Folder); %java file object
jNames = jFile.list; %java string objects
Match = arrayfun(@(f)f.startsWith('page')&f.endsWith('.sys'),jNames); %boolean
cellstr(char(jNames(Match))) %cellstr
```

%Example: list all class methods

```
methods(handle(jPaths(1)))
methods(handle(jNames(1)))
```